# Amazon Micro Instance Crashed - Help Me Figure Out Why?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, server-crashes

I am running an Amazon AWS Micro Linux Instance and it crashed during some "light" usage a few days ago. I am running an app that uploads photos to the server. We had maybe 10 users uploading multiple photos during a 1 hour period.

At some point, the server stopped responding. I logged into the AWS Console and found that the "Intstance Reachability Check" had failed. I rebooted the server, restarted PHP and MySQL, and then had to repair a few MySQL tables that had been corrupted.

I had the monitoring tools turned on and the CPU Usage indicates that we topped out at 28% CPU Usage - After reading some more documentation about Micro Instances, I do not think we maxed out on the CPU, but I could be wrong.

I don't know a enough to understand what the logs mean. I have found what I believe to be the logs from the server from the time where the problem occurred, I am hoping that someone can help me decipher what happened:

> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157082] httpd
>   invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157100] httpd
>   cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157108] Pid: 1824,
>   comm: httpd Not tainted 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157117] Call Trace:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157131] 
>   [] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x98/0xa0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157143] 
>   [] dump_header.clone.1+0x77/0x1a0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157153] 
>   [] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157164] 
>   [] ? ___ratelimit+0x9f/0x120
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157172] 
>   [] oom_kill_process.clone.0+0x76/0x140
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157185] 
>   [] __out_of_memory+0x118/0x190
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157196] 
>   [] out_of_memory+0x82/0x1c0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157204] 
>   [] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x689/0x6a0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157215] 
>   [] alloc_pages_current+0x94/0xf0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157223] 
>   [] __page_cache_alloc+0x7f/0x90
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157232] 
>   [] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc0/0x200
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157240] 
>   [] ra_submit+0x1c/0x20
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157248] 
>   [] filemap_fault+0x3e3/0x430
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157257] 
>   [] __do_fault+0x4f/0x4b0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157265] 
>   [] handle_mm_fault+0x1b4/0xb40
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157275] 
>   [] ? xen_clocksource_read+0x21/0x30
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157283] 
>   [] ? xen_clocksource_get_cycles+0x9/0x10
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157293] 
>   [] ? ktime_get_ts+0xa3/0xd0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157302] 
>   [] do_page_fault+0x112/0x310
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157310] 
>   [] page_fault+0x25/0x30
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157316] Mem-Info:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157320] Node 0 DMA
>   per-cpu:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157327] CPU    0:
>   hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157332] Node 0
>   DMA32 per-cpu:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157339] CPU    0:
>   hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel:
>   [19699669.157347] active_anon:70901 inactive_anon:71000
>   isolated_anon:0Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel:
>   [19699669.157348]  active_file:13 inactive_file:28 isolated_file:0Jul
>   23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157349]  unevictable:0
>   dirty:4 writeback:0 unstable:0Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel:
>   [19699669.157350]  free:1374 slab_reclaimable:613
>   slab_unreclaimable:1843
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157351]  mapped:25
>   shmem:34 pagetables:4842 bounce:0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157430] Node 0 DMA
>   free:2436kB min:76kB low:92kB high:112kB active_anon:6104kB
>   inactive_anon:6272kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB
>   isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15772kB mlocked:0kB
>   dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB
>   slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:20kB unstable:0kB
>   bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157459]
>   lowmem_reserve[]: 0 590 590 590
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157475] Node 0
>   DMA32 free:3060kB min:3068kB low:3832kB high:4600kB
>   active_anon:277500kB inactive_anon:277728kB active_file:52kB
>   inactive_file:112kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0k B
>   isolated(file):0kB present:604988kB mlocked:0kB dirty:16kB
>   writeback:0kB mapped:100kB shmem:136kB slab_reclaimable:2452kB
>   slab_unreclaimable:7372kB kernel_stack:752kB pagetables:19348kB
>   unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pa ges_scanned:256
>   all_unreclaimable? yes
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157503]
>   lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157518] Node 0 DMA:
>   1*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB
>   1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2436kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157553] Node 0
>   DMA32: 729*4kB 4*8kB 5*16kB 1*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB
>   0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3060kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157587] 80 total
>   pagecache pages
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157592] 0 pages in
>   swap cache
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157597] Swap cache
>   stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157602] Free swap 
>   = 0kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.157607] Total swap
>   = 0kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.158050] 157439
>   pages RAM
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.158050] 4626 pages
>   reserved
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.158050] 38855 pages
>   shared
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.158050] 149663
>   pages non-shared
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.158050] Out of
>   memory: kill process 2135 (httpd) score 87500 or a child
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.158050] Killed
>   process 2135 (httpd) vsz:350000kB, anon-rss:49376kB, file-rss:0kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.164960] httpd
>   invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.164990] httpd
>   cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.164998] Pid: 1824,
>   comm: httpd Not tainted 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165006] Call Trace:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165020] 
>   [] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x98/0xa0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165032] 
>   [] dump_header.clone.1+0x77/0x1a0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165042] 
>   [] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165053] 
>   [] ? ___ratelimit+0x9f/0x120
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165061] 
>   [] oom_kill_process.clone.0+0x76/0x140
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165069] 
>   [] __out_of_memory+0x118/0x190
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165077] 
>   [] out_of_memory+0x82/0x1c0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165086] 
>   [] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x689/0x6a0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165096] 
>   [] alloc_pages_current+0x94/0xf0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165105] 
>   [] __page_cache_alloc+0x7f/0x90
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165114] 
>   [] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc0/0x200
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165122] 
>   [] ra_submit+0x1c/0x20
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165129] 
>   [] filemap_fault+0x3e3/0x430
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165139] 
>   [] __do_fault+0x4f/0x4b0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165147] 
>   [] handle_mm_fault+0x1b4/0xb40
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165156] 
>   [] ? xen_clocksource_read+0x21/0x30
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165164] 
>   [] ? xen_clocksource_get_cycles+0x9/0x10
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165178] 
>   [] ? ktime_get_ts+0xa3/0xd0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165187] 
>   [] do_page_fault+0x112/0x310
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165195] 
>   [] page_fault+0x25/0x30
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165201] Mem-Info:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165205] Node 0 DMA
>   per-cpu:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165212] CPU    0:
>   hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165217] Node 0
>   DMA32 per-cpu:
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165224] CPU    0:
>   hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 130
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165232]
>   active_anon:70836 inactive_anon:71000 isolated_anon:0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165233] 
>   active_file:13 inactive_file:28 isolated_file:0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165234] 
>   unevictable:0 dirty:4 writeback:0 unstable:0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165235]  free:1343
>   slab_reclaimable:613 slab_unreclaimable:1843
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165236]  mapped:25
>   shmem:34 pagetables:4842 bounce:0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165262] Node 0 DMA
>   free:2436kB min:76kB low:92kB high:112kB active_anon:6104kB
>   inactive_anon:6272kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB
>   isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15772kB mlocked:0kB
>   dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB
>   slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:20kB unstable:0kB
>   bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165290]
>   lowmem_reserve[]: 0 590 590 590
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165305] Node 0
>   DMA32 free:2936kB min:3068kB low:3832kB high:4600kB
>   active_anon:277240kB inactive_anon:277728kB active_file:52kB
>   inactive_file:112kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB
>   isolated(file):0kB present:604988kB mlocked:0kB dirty:16kB
>   writeback:0kB mapped:100kB shmem:136kB slab_reclaimable:2452kB
>   slab_unreclaimable:7372kB kernel_stack:752kB pagetables:19348kB
>   unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pa ges_scanned:256
>   all_unreclaimable? yes
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165334]
>   lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel:
>   [19699669.165348] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 1*128kB
>   1*25 6kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2436kBJul 23 00:19:07
>   ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165420] Node 0 DMA32: 710*4kB 4*8kB
>   4*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB  0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB
>   0*4096kB = 2936kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] 80 total
>   pagecache pages
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] 0 pages in
>   swap cache
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] Swap cache
>   stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] Free swap 
>   = 0kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] Total swap
>   = 0kB
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] 157439
>   pages RAM
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] 4626 pages
>   reserved
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] 37922 pages
>   shared
>
> Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] 149594
>   pages non-sharedJul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel:
>   [19699669.165648] Out of memory: kill process 1859 (httpd) score 87366
>   or a  childJul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648]
>   Killed process 1859 (httpd) vsz:349464kB, anon-rss:49312k B,
>   file-rss:0kB

Please let me know if there is anything additional that I can provide.

Comment: Do you even bother to read the logs?
`Jul 23 00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165290] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 590 590 590`
`00:19:07 ip-10-117-66-219 kernel: [19699669.165648] Out of memory: kill process 1859 (httpd) score 87366 or a child`
`

Comment: I see several references to running out of memory.  When that happens GNU/Linux starts killing random processes. (I never figured out why this was better than just returning OOM).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/134669/how-to-diagnose-causes-of-oom-killer-killing-processes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux out-of-memory killer felt obliged to free some RAM. Which it then attempted to do (httpd being the logged target). However, it looks like it was not successful enough and ended up locking up hard, which would not get logged since the server was out of RAM and thus didn't have memory for log-buffers.

Comment: So given the information here, I would need to upgrade to a server with more RAM. Whenever it talks about "Memory" I do not know if it is referencing RAM or disk space. Thank You.

Comment: You've got two options: You can tune your server processes to use less RAM (apache in particular in its default configuration can use more RAM than you have) or upgrade to a larger EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3):

You're out of memory. It's a small instance that doesn't have enough RAM to support your application. You're a victim of the [OOM Killer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory).